# perl reference hash slice

Tags: perl, reference

I have below hash:

```
my %gilligan_info = (
        name            =>      'Gilligan',
        hat             =>      'white',
        shirt           =>      'Red',
        position        =>      'First Mate',
);

my %skipper_info = (
        name            =>      'Skipper',
        hat             =>      'Black',
        shirt           =>      'Blue',
        position        =>      'Captain'
);
```

I have a array of hashes:

```
my @crew = (\%gilligan_info, \%skipper_info);
```

I created a reference:

```
my $ref = \%{$crew[1]};
```

I'm pulling key values from second hash:

```
my @ref_values = @{$ref}{ qw ( name position hat )};
```

My question is, how can I get values of hashes by not specifying element number in reference "$ref"?

Thanks

Comment: What is your desired result for above example?

Comment: I would like to specify the desired element in "@ref_values"

Comment: So what should be content of `@ref_values`?

Comment: Values of keys in hash

Comment: The structure you seem to be looking for is a hash: `my %hash = (Gilligan => \%gilligan_info, Skipper => \%skipper_info); my @ref_vals = @{$hash{Skipper}}{qw (name position hat) };`

Comment: `\%{$crew[1]}` is identical to `$crew[1]`

Comment: *'how can I get values of hashes by not specifying element number in reference `$ref`?'* I don't understand. You have to specify an element number to say which element of `@crew` you want to process. What am I missing?

Comment: @Borodin Is it possible for "$ref" to just contain "@$crew", and specify which element I want in "@ref_values"

Comment: You can write it so that `@ref_values` contains *all* of the values, and `$ref_values[1]` is `[ 'Skipper', 'Captain', 'Black' ]`. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want values of all hashes in single array,

```
my @ref_values = map @$_{ qw(name position hat) }, @crew;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is for `@ref_values` to contain an array of values for each of the `@crew`.

Something like this, perhaps

```
my @ref_values;

for my $crew ( @crew ) {
  push @ref_values, [ @$crew{ qw(name position hat) } ];
}
```

This is also possible using `map` if you prefer, similarly to the solution from `Сухой27`

Comment: Thanks. Is there Amy way I can use "$ref" reference instead of directly using "@crew"?

Comment: @SamPinar: Well yes, but in your own code `$ref` is a copy of just the second element of `@crew` so you wouldn't be able to access the first element through it. I'm thinking perhaps you need to show us the *real* problem to get a proper answer

Comment: All I want to do is use $ref = \%{$crew} (not pointing to a specific element) and write syntax in $ref_values which points to element I want

Comment: @SamPinar: Well as I pointed out, `$ref = \%{$crew}` is identical to `$ref = $crew`, and besides you have no `$crew` variable. If you take `$ref = \@crew` then you can replace `@crew` in my solution with `@$ref`